# Calculating modulo with result, offset, and input.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am new to modulo and how it is used so sorry if the question is dumb.
Trying to code a program (based on videos of a similar program) that uses modulo.

[Image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po0mv.png)

IGNORE Bottom image

To explain more on the picture.
We have 3 numbers that we know.

```
original number = (left, 1. right,5000)
offset = (7359)
result = (left, 7360. right,3471)
```

This means on the picture above I enter 1 and get 7360.
Meaning there is an offset and it's 7359.

When I input 5000 tho instead of getting 12359(5000+7359) i get 3471.

Meaning there is probably a modulo operation in place.

What I want to know is what is the divisor and dividend for this above picture.

I want to know this so i can calculate results based on an original number i input and offset.

Comment: What is the question?  I gather you have some (unknown?) function which you know a few values of.  Is that correct?   If so, what do you know about this function?  You must know something (else there is very little to say).

Comment: As it stands, your question is not clear at all.  It's not even grammatical:  "When I input 5000, i can 3471." isn't English.  Please edit for clarity.  Explain, clearly, what you know and what it is you would like to deduce.

Comment: Looks like $8471 = [5000 \times (1)] + 3471.$  In the same way, $7360 = [7359 \times (1)] + 1.$  I am just guessing.

Comment: @lulu understandable reaction that I still regard as somewhat harsh.  New + language difficulties influences me to try to bridge the gap with a guess, as a first communication.

Comment: @lulu Added a picture to show what I mean and what is the calculation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **If** I am guessing your intent correctly, normally, these types of relationships are expressed as $a = Pb + r$, where $a$ is an integer, $b$ is a positive integer, $P$ is an integer, and $r \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, (b-1)\}.$  Known as the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think the link helps.  At least it doesn't help me.  Are you trying to guess a number?  A function?

Comment: Just to say:  If you are saying that you have some, unknown, number $n$ such that $5000\equiv 3471\pmod n$ then all we know about $n$ is that it divides $5000-3741=1259$.  Now, as it happens, $1259$ is a prime, so that means that $n=1259$ (I am assuming that we know that $n>1$).  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Community My compliments : of the 30+ similar comments that I have seen you make, this is the first time that such a compliment is appropriate.

Comment: updating question, sorry for it being bad first time on this forum :D

Comment: @lulu user2661923
Sorry for the confusion, updated question hope it's clearer

Comment: I don't know about anyone else.  I still don't know what you are asking.  Is it possible that you could express the desired relationship mathematically?  If it isn't of the form $a = Pb + r$, re one of my previous comments, could you please try to take a stab at what you are trying to accomplish.  This is like *code-breaking*.  More data needed to see a pattern.  Alternatively, perhaps, you could experiment with small positive integers less than $20$, to try to reveal a mathematical pattern.

Comment: Ok...so I think that you then seek $n$ such that $12359 \equiv 3471\pmod n$  If so, then $n$ must divide the difference, $12359-3471=8888$.  Now, we also know that $n>7360$ (else $7360$ could not have been an output), and the only divisor of $8888$ which is that large is $8888$ itself, so $n=8888$.  Sound good?

Comment: To stress:  I am still just guessing what you are asking, but I think I'm on to something.  Anyway, test my answer.  Should be easy enough to see if I have  hit the mark or not.

Comment: @lulu that's what I got as well.

Comment: @lulu You are correct, run some calculations and it works ty for the help and sorry for the bad question.

Please post as an answer so I can mark it as the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

There is an (unknown) modulus $n$, and we are considering the function $$f(n)\equiv n+7359\pmod n$$

We'd like to compute $n$.

We know two values:

$$f(1)=7360\quad \&\quad f(5000)=3471$$

From the first, we deduce that $n>7360$.  From the second we deduce that $$n\,|\,(5000+735
9)-3471=8888$$

Happily, $8888$ only has one divisor which is greater than $7360$, namely $8888$ itself.  Hence $$\boxed {n=8888}$$